# SSL Ceriticate & Htaccess & SEO

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, seo

I want to add ssl certificate to my news site. But dont want to get SEO penalty or seo rank reduction with changing **http** url's to **https**..

my htaccess file is like this now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and im planning to change it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http**s**://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and also, i will convert all http url's to https in html source...

is it enough to **not to get penalized by Google?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice (if something gets penalized). It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change `http` url's to `https`, but only when the url is without `www`.

Use instead:

```
# Without IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Or if you use it with other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.|[0-9.]+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: can i say, 'add www; except IP adress usage'.. because: with normal .com url is ok... but, this conditions adds www. before IP; if i write IP adresses to open the site..

Comment: I just add test for that